# Objective C property vs ivar issues with Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, scope

I spent several hours trying to figure out this problem, and I think it comes down to my fundamental understanding of Objective C, though it manifested through working on Core Data. I'm not surprised - I've only been working with Objective C and Cocoa Touch for just two months now.

My situation is that I have a series of models that are all connected fine in the CD. My app works just fine until I tried extending it yesterday. I have my main model Job in a view controller as a class property in the .h file. In my viewWillAppear method I have to look up a relationship through another object, so I do something like:

```
/** project as an ivar **/
NSManagedObject *project = [job valueForKey:@"project"];
NSArray *divisions = [[project valueForKey:@"divisions"] allObjects];
//do something with divisions --> crash
```

...

```
/** project as a property **/
project = [job valueForKey:@"project"];
NSArray *divisions = [[project valueForKey:@"divisions"] allObjects];
//do someting, anything ---> A-OK!
```

So, why does my app crash when I try to do things with the results of [project valueForKey:] unless I make project a class property?

### EDIT

It appears that simply including the `if(!divisions)` conditional in there (which it should be null when the view first loads), it doesn't like the statements I provided above and produces the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. However, when leaving it out, my code works fine.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if(!divisions){

        NSManagedObject *project = [[job valueForKey:@"project"] retain];
        NSArray *divs = [[project valueForKey:@"divisions"] allObjects];

        NSSortDescriptor *alphaSort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"order" ascending:YES];
        divisions = [[divs sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:alphaSort]] mutableCopy];

    }
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}
```

I'll accept that there's a bigger memory management problem going on. Should I probably go back and re-read some book chapters on Obj-C and retrace my variables so it makes sense?

Comment: Just a guess, but do you have `retain` set on the property? Also, if you are able to post the error when it crashes that may help us help you!

Comment: What does the crash log say in the first case?

Comment: In the first case, project is a local variable, not an ivar. In the second case you are using project as an ivar, not as a property. You have some larger memory mgmt problem here, more code/context would help.

Comment: I wouldn't doubt that I have some memory management issues going on - I'm coming from a PHP, JS type background. I kind of get the ideas of memory management, but I know I really don't fully understand all the ins and outs. The crash is just a EXC_BAD_ACCESS and gives no indication otherwise in the debugger

Comment: @firoze-lafeer I'm sure I have the terms mixed up. The second case I have project defined in my .h file @implementation. @Dean-Pucsek adding retain doesn't seem to change it. I'm working on the code a little bit more and I'm wondering if there's some other kind of bug going on here that appears to affecting what's really going on.

Comment: It certainly sounds like there are some other bug(s) going on here. You have to be careful not to get fixated on symptoms and miss the root causes. For one thing, memory management is easier (generally) if you use @properties, which is doesn't appear you are doing here. (Not just declare, but actually *use* them). And other than that, you have to take a step back and look not at these few lines of code, but generally how are you managing project and divisions objects in this VC and in your app in general. Each hour spent really studying memory mgmt is worth hundreds of hours of debugging.

Comment: @Firoze-Lafeer That's what I'm finding. This is my first "real" app that's bigger than just a VC or two, so it's been quite a learning curve. I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for certain based on the limited code provided but the simplest explaination for the crash is that you don't check if the `divs` or the `divisions` arrays are empty before performing any operations on them.

If the `Project.divisions` relationship is empty this:

```
NSArray *divs = [[project valueForKey:@"divisions"] allObjects];
```

... will return an empty array. Any attempt to address any element of the array e.g. `[divs objectAtIndex:0]` will produce an error.

Also, `divisions` appears to be an iVar of the controller object but you don't use either the preferred `self.divisions` reference form nor a `[divisions retain]` when assigning the 'divs' array to it. Since the `divs` array will be returned autoreleased, it will be purged when the pool next drains and the array in `divisions` will disappear even if it is not empty.

Simply change `divisions` to `self.divisions` to fix.

Comment: I didn't realize that `self.divisions` was required because just typing out `divisions` seemed to work. That should be easy enough to fix in general, but quite a bit of work throughout the app to get it consistent. Not impossible, just maybe a bit tedious. Thanks for the great tip!

Answer (score -1):

Apart from the ivar confusion your code has two other problems. When accessing an attribute on an NSManagedObject you should use primitiveValueForKey: as in

```
[job willAccessValueForKey:@"project"];
NSManagedObject *project = [job primitiveValueForKey:@"project"];
[job didAccessValueForKey:@"project"];
```

Any time you get or set a property of an existing managed object, you should always precede the call with willAccessValueForKey: and close with didAccessValueForKey: so that the model and the store stay in sync.

Even better would be

```
[job willAccessValueForKey:@"project"];
NSManagedObject *project = [job primitiveProject];
[job didAccessValueForKey:@"project"];
```

but unfortunately the Xcode debugger doesn't grok that and you have to put up with those annoying yellow warnings.

Furthermore, an NSManagedObject relationship returns an NSSet not an array:

```
[project willAccessValueForKey:@"divisions"];
NSSet *divisions = [project primitiveValueForKey:@"divisions"];
[project didAccessValueForKey:@"divisions"];
```

Read more in Apple's [Model Object Implementation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ModelObjects/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154)

Lastly, if you're doing all this to populate a table, you're much better off instantiating an NSFetchedResultsController which is optimized for precisely that task.

Comment: @Elise... maybe reading "Stranger in a Strange Land" would help with the 'grok' usage (grin).

Comment: Linking errors *and* a nerd faux pas? I should have stayed in bed. I'll put it on my reading list. BTW, I thought it was a Hitchiker's quote -- Zaphod Beeblebrox if memory serves. But then, the lamented Mr. Adams was a well-read man.

Comment: -1 Sorry for the downcheck but in this circumstance you most definitely would not want to use `primativeValueForKey`. Primitive accessors are used almost exclusively within custom accessors in NSManagedObject subclasses or in mass data imports. When you use primitive methods you turn off all the "manage" in managedObjects which can cause your object graph to become scrambled. He is also on iOS and can't use an array controller.

Comment: Upon rereading the Model Object Implementation Guide, I do believe you are right. I've been using primitiveValueForKey: without problems on a store which hasn't changed in ages, but indeed if the model did contain faults, problems would have ensued. Amending my answer accordingly.